# Promoted Links with different sizes in same Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, javascript, promoted-links, script

I have a complicated requirement in which I have to embed a promoted link with different sizes and styles in the same SharePoint page.

Figure at the bottom illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

It has a three promoted links with three different views. I am using three different web parts that will include these three different promoted link's views.

I can resize the tile size by pure CSS as suggested by an answer in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86743/change-the-default-tile-size-in-sharepoint-2013). I am using this CSS in Script Editor -1 as in figure below.

I can control how many tiles to display per row as suggested by [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19622.sharepoint-2013-promoted-links-wrap-tiles.aspx). And I am using this Java Script in Script Editor - 2.

I want these script editor's to affect only the promoted link view in Web Part - 3. Promoted Link's in Web Part - 1 and Web Part - 2 should be untouched.

Kindly suggest how this can be done.

Thanks

[image: Promoted Links in a page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your webparts should have its own unique ID in the code.  Use developer tools (F12) to examine your page.

You should be able to then target CSS to only elements inside of a particular ID

Web Part 1's ID is a  called #content

To target class elements inside only Web Part 1, you would do something like div#content.myClass