# SharePoint Promoted Links remove animation on hover

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to have promoted links app without the hover action which has an animation? Please suggest me how we could do that? Waiting for an early response.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions on network. Using CSS, Jquery and XSLT.
Please check below:
1) Using Script:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d9156516-1298-48ae-8e31-c67eab56f786/i-want-to-remove-the-roll-over-effect-from-my-promoted-link?forum=sharepointdevelopment

2) Using CSS:
[change the default tile size in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86743/change-the-default-tile-size-in-sharepoint-2013)

3) Using script and multiple formatting of promoted links:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx

Hope this will help someone.