# Increase tile size of promoted link in Share point 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development

I create an app using the Promoted Links in Sharepoint 2013. I chose to do this because the feature has the awesome hover effect and is easy to customize the image.

The issue is that I have been trying to figure out how to change the tile sizes. They are awesome the way they are, however I just need them smaller. I still want the hover effect as well and for the text to match the same ratio as the tile. I have tried web zones, I have done each ID but with no luck. Please help.

Same question asked before:
[change the default tile size in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86743/change-the-default-tile-size-in-sharepoint-2013)

But this was for decrees the size for tile.

Comment: check this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx

Comment: Just take the css from your example's answer (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86743/change-the-default-tile-size-in-sharepoint-2013) and apply your desired size

Comment: @Mx, I tried but Hover effect still showing in small size.

Comment: @Waqs Sarwar MCSE, jquery is not working at my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to work with browser tools to fiddle with CSS - press F12 to access the tools in common browsers.

Here's your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        div.ms-promlink-body {
            height: 200px;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
            height: 210px !important;
            width: 210px !important;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > span {
            height: 200px !important;
            width: 200px !important;
        }            

        div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox{
            margin-top:40px;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img {
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > span {
              margin-left: 25px;
              margin-top: 25px;
        }

        ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
            height: 200px;
        }

        .ms-tileview-tile-titleMediumCollapsed {
            height: 50px;
        }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mx. for you reply. I tried it but no working as expected at my side. I have two promoted Link on same page. For first, I decrees the tile size and look good but another whose tile need to increase is not working.

Comment: @user2493287 This works well on OOTB tiles. I cant help you as i dont know whats wrong in your environment.

Comment: @Max, Now, I can set image size as expected but problem with the shadow not coming properly on Expand and Collapsed. Got good link:                                  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ab960b52-8013-469a-8fd5-05a7230e6337/sharepoint-2013-tile-size-css-                                                                                                                                      This link tell us that we cant change top position of shadow as it is hard-coded.

Comment: @Max, I used your css, but it is showing half shadow on tile which is my main problem now.

Comment: @user2493287 as I said - this works OOTB. When this isn't working for you there is something that applies wrong styles to the tiles.

Comment: @Max, I can see attached image at your answer. Its showing shadow over half image. I want to solve it. I don't think it working at your end as well. Image is showing the shadow problem.