# SharePoint 2013 Promoted Link tile sizing?

Tags: size, tiles

I am trying to resize promoted links tiles to 250px x 250px however am struggling to find a correct method of doing so. These have pictures and title/information text. I've seen some Javascript methods however there appears to be a limitation on how big these tiles can be.

The solution below worked however I am now trying to sort the hover over animation.

The below image shows the tiles I've just created on the bottom row - we'd like them to display the mouseover the same as on the top row and only show the tile description and not the title itself. But only show this on mouse-over. So the tile would be completely clear before hand.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following CSS inside a Script Editor web part

```
<style type="text/css">

  /*  tile row height */
  div.ms-promlink-body {
    height: 100px;
  }

  /*  tile dimensions, including inter-tile margin */
  div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
    width: 110px !important;
    height: 110px !important;
  }

  /*  tile and title( + description) overlay dimensions */
  div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: 250px !important;
  }

  /*  tile background image dimensions */
  div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  /*  title and description text  */
  ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px 7px 7px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
  }

  /*  description text class  */
  li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }

  /*  title text when description not shown  */
  div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 86px;
    height: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 4px 7px 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 13px;
  }

</style>
```

[Ref](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86743/change-the-default-tile-size-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: I've updated my original query with some more information.

Comment: Dear @surfnode, as you mentioned on your updated quest "The solution below worked"  then you update it with new requirement , so should you tell me why you don't want to help me as I tried to help you, "the upvote" button is for answer that is useful and "set as answer" button  if it solved your issue so Please, don't hesitate to upvote it and if it considered an answer to your question kindly set it as Answer,

Comment: OK I've ticked your original comment as being helpful. If you read the rest of the first entry it will explain what I want to do with the mouse-over bits. Sorry.